# Why am I getting token as undefined when using middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, middleware

I am using nodejs and express to develop a small application which uses android for the front-end. I wanted to implement session tokens for which I am using Json-Web Tokens.

I have a separate route defined for the middleware to check if user is authorised.

```
router.use(function(req,res,next)
{
    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['xtoken'];

    if (token)
    {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token,"SECRET-KEY", function(err, decoded) 
        {      
            if (err)
            {
                return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });    
            } 
            else
            {
                console.log("Successful token is ",decoded.token)
                req.decoded = decoded;    
                next();
            }
        });
    } 
    else 
    {
        return res.status(403).send(
        { 
            success: false  
        });
    }
});
```

I need a separate route to read a form which consists of some data and multiple files. The form details are posted to /user/new-order, a request is made within the above route separately to a  new route /user/file/upload where each file is uploaded one-by-one

Here is the problem. 
I want to read the session token on every route. When I first make a request to POST some form data, the middleware reads the session token and accepts the form fields BUT as it goes to the route to upload a single file, the token is undefined and I am prevented from accessing the page.

I have tried logging the values of the session token in the route /user/file/upload AND while the middleware stores the session token as undefined, The route user/file/upload is able to read the token.

The Android front-end uses a single screen to accept form and file upload.
The user/new-order route is as below :

```
router.post('/new-order',function(req,res)
{   
    var subject = req.body.subject;
    var Format = req.body.Format;       //Reference FORMAT or FORMATS ?
    var email = req.email
    var token = req.body.token
    console.log("Form token is ",token)       
});
```

The user/upload/file route is below :

```
router.post('/upload/file',uploadtype,function(req,res)
{
    var file = req.file 
    var token = req.body.token
    console.log("File token is ",token)         

});
```

The middleware to read session data is above the assignment routes.

```
app.use('/user',session)
app.use('/user',assignment)
```

This is the output :

**Successful token is : token_value**

**Form token is : token_value**

**Successful token is : undefined**

**File token is : token_value**

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I would really appreciate some tips and pointers.

Please let me know if what I have provided is not enough, I will add it immediately.

Much appreciated.